# Filtering a collection using the @Filter hibernate annotation in java

Tags: hibernate

I have two hibernate mapped entities A and B.

A has 2 collections of entity B and I would like to filter each collection based on a property held in B (as shown in code below).

```
@FilterDefs()
class A{

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "productType", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@Filter(name = "something", condition = "entityType = 'SKU1'")  
Set<B> set1 = new HashSet<B>();

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "productType", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@Filter(name = "something", condition = "entityType = 'SKU2'")  
Set<B> set2 = new HashSet<B>();

 }

class B{

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private A productType;

@Column(name = "entity_type")
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private EntityType entityType;
}
```

Edited:
I am enabling the filters as suggested below in my DAO method.  However, I am getting the following exception

> org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not initialize a
>   collection

If i use the eager loading method, I am getting an exception to do with invalid SQL getting generated?

Any pointers?

Comment: Can you add more of the stack trace?

Answer (score 6):

I use FilterDef in the Entity and then set in wich collections I want to use the filter. In your example:

```
class A{
@OneToMany(...)
@Filter(name = "filterName")  
Set<B> set2 = new HashSet<B>();
}

@FilterDef(name = "filterName", 
    defaultCondition = condition,
    parameters = {@ParamDef(name = nameParameter,
    type = typeParameter)})
class B{
}
```

Then as ssedano said you should enable filter in the session:

```
session.enableFilter("filterName")
```

And put the params if it is the case:

```
session.getEnabledFilter(filterName).setParameter(nameParameter,value);
```

Answer (score 0):

You must enable the filter in the DAO.

```
session.enableFilter("something");
```

Before retrieve the objects.

Comment: As you suggested, I am enabling the filter in my DAO but am getting the following exception: org.hibernate.HibernateException: No such filter configured [something].. Do I need to create a FilterDef or place an entry elsewhere?

Comment: check your filter definition specially check type. you should use primitive type such as string, integer, long and ... it is important if you need list to send as parameter value; you should user setParameterList() instead of setParameter().