# Filtering JPA eager fetched entites

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a bunch of JPA entites (witch Hibernate) called Nodes, with the following fields:

- NodeId
- ParentNodeId
- Active

The ParentNodeId refers to another Node, so I have a nice tree structure.

I've set the fetch type of Node to eager, so I get all the elements in the tree.

What I would like to do, is to filter the tree by *Active* property, that is get only those nodes, which has its *Active* field set to 1.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Thank,
krisy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [hibernate filter](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/filters.html)

1. To define `@FilterDef` at entity class level

   ```
   @Entity
   @FilterDef (name="nodeFilter", 
               parameters = @ParamDef( name="activeParam", type="integer" ))
   ```
2. Then define `@Filter` on desired property (at property level or at class level)

   ```
   @Filter(name = "nodeFilter", condition = "active = :activeParam")
   ```
3. Finally **ENABLE** the filter whenever/wherever you want (e.g findAllNodes() )

   ```
   Filter filter = session.enableFilter("nodeFilter");
   filter.setParameter("activeParam", 1);  //e.g Active is 1
   //then retrieve the result from session
   ```

More references : [link1](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-data-filter-example-xml-and-annotation/), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7805572/filtering-a-collection-using-the-filter-hibernate-annotation-in-java), [link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15844220/hibernate-multiple-filters-on-an-entity)